# Recover ADSL password for my Linksys WAG54G2

Tags: router, adsl, password-recovery

I have a Linksys WAG54G2 ADSL router and I want to change my router. The problem is that I don't know what my ADSL password is (I'm not talking about the router's login page). I contacted my ISP about this and their assistant said the manager won't be there for at least 2 days. I wonder is there any other way I can recover this password from my router itself?

Comment: Routers often have something like a "backup configuration" option that gives you a text file of the settings. Is there one of those on your router?

Comment: Can't the ISP assistant simply reset your password to a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the password is displayed but masked with `*****` on the router's configuration page, typically http://192.168.1.1 for *your* router, you can install the [Web Developer toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) in firefox or chrome and use the option `Form -> show passwords` to display the password in plain text.

If that doesn't work, then here are [4 more options to recover your ADSL password](http://blog.nirsoft.net/2010/06/14/how-to-recover-lost-adsl-password-or-other-isp-password/), as long as you're on a Windows machine.

If you're on Linux or Unix, [try this instead](http://ubercoder.blogspot.com/2006/11/shell-script-to-recover-adsl-passwords.html).

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.